# PHP as a low level proxy

Tags: php

Is it possible to use PHP as a low level proxy where it simply redirects all the traffic you send to it to another server and any traffic coming from the server back to the client? (without interpreting it as the traffic is not always HTTP)

Any code examples of this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about *TCP-only* traffic or *every* kind of traffic ?

Comment: Take a look at sockets: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php. Anyway, php is not the best choice here, imho.

Comment: It is possible to accomplish nearly *anything* with PHP. Is it the best language? No.

Comment: @HalimQarroum TCP only but any protocol

Comment: @PLB I realize that PHP is definately not the best language for it but it is my only option.

Comment: @user1109519 Sadly. In that case you have to play around with sockets.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The reason I thought it might be impossible is because you likely need at least two threads to get the IO going. If it is indeed possible, great. However in that case I still need some code because I don't really see how it should be done.

Comment: @user1109519 [Here's _experimental_ library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) for threading. Also you can use traditional approaches (starting new php process).

Comment: Are you able to use [`exec()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)? That may open up some additional possibilities.